# How do I get the coordinates for finger tapping in UIView?

Tags: iphone, coordinates

How do I get the coordinates for finger tapping in UIView?
(I would prefer not to use a big array of buttons)

Thank you

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There’re two ways to accomplish this. If you’ve already got a subclass of UIView that you’re using, you can just override the `-touchesEnded:withEvent:` method on that subclass, like this:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [aTouch locationInView:self];
    // point.x and point.y have the coordinates of the touch
}
```

If you’re not already subclassing UIView, though, and the view is owned by a view controller or whatever, then you can use a UITapGestureRecognizer, like this:

```
// when the view's initially set up (in viewDidLoad, for example)
UITapGestureRecognizer *rec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized:)];
[someView addGestureRecognizer:rec];
[rec release];

// elsewhere
- (void)tapRecognized:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
    {
        CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
        // again, point.x and point.y have the coordinates
    }
}
```

Comment: touchesEnded:withEvent: can be used from UIViewController too, as that is also derived from UIResponder.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3 answer

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapAction(_:)))
yourView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


func tapAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

      let point = sender.location(in: yourView)


}
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean recognizing gestures (and touches).  The best place to start looking for such a broad question is Apple's sample code [Touches](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435). It walks through a good amount of information.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:myView];
    NSLog("%lf %lf", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
}
```

You need to do something like this. `touchesBegan:withEvent:` is a method of `UIResponder` from which `UIView` and `UIViewController` both are derived. If you google for this method then you will find several tutorials. [MoveMe](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html) sample from Apple is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

```
func handleFrontTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap working")
    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Recognized
    { 
      `print(gestureRecognizer.locationInView(gestureRecognizer.view))`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.6:

You can override the following in your UIResponder (which both UIView and UIViewController inherit from):

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let point = touch.location(in: someView)
        print("x = \(point.x), y = \(point.y)")
    }
}
```

Or in your gesture recognizer handler:

```
@objc func handleLongPress(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: someView)
    print("x = \(point.x), y = \(point.y)")

}
```