# How to get the coordinate of a UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

In my app, I use PanGesture.

Now, I have a UIImageView within my main view and I can drag my UIImageView within the main view.

To which axis in the main view I have to drag my UIImageView?

Comment: No I just need the point x axis and y axis where I am tapping within the view

Comment: do you want UIImageview coordinate or UIView ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to move your object
or link for best tutorials http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, 
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view];
    CGFloat magnitude = sqrtf((velocity.x * velocity.x) + (velocity.y * velocity.y));
    CGFloat slideMult = magnitude / 200;
    NSLog(@"magnitude: %f, slideMult: %f", magnitude, slideMult);

    float slideFactor = 0.1 * slideMult; // Increase for more of a slide
    CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + (velocity.x * slideFactor), 
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + (velocity.y * slideFactor));
    finalPoint.x = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.x, 0), self.view.bounds.size.width);
    finalPoint.y = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.y, 0), self.view.bounds.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:slideFactor*2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        recognizer.view.center = finalPoint;
    } completion:nil];

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use frame property of a UIView class.which gives you top,left,width and height of the view.

```
NSLog(@"view.frame.origin.x : %f",view.frame.origin.x);
NSLog(@"view.frame.origin.y : %f",view.frame.origin.y);
NSLog(@"view.frame.size.width : %f",view.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"view.frame.size.height : %f",view.frame.size.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below APIs to translate your points from one view to other and vice versa.

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view;
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point fromView:(UIView *)view;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (IBAction)panGestureReceived:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

        if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            myVarToStoreTheBeganPosition = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
        } else if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
           CGPoint myNewPositionAtTheEnd = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
           // and now handle it ;)
        } else if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
           CGPoint myNewPositionAtTheEnd = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
           // and now handle it ;)
        }
    }
```

Comment: No I just need the point x axis and y axis where I am tapping within the view

Comment: Go to the link here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113860/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-for-finger-tapping-in-uiview