# How to get a position of uicollectionview

Tags: uicollectionview

I want to get touch position, when user touch on uicollectionView(or on custom cell in uicollectionview it doesn't matter).

can someone help me?

Comment: Same as you would any UIView subclass... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113860/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-for-finger-tapping-in-uiview

Comment: thank you for your answer. However this is not what i am look. When i add gesture on collectionview, it override -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method. I need that method and the position at same time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get the index of touched UICollectionCell

```
    let indexpath = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first
```

To get the position of a UICollectionCell relative to the view, in which it's located

```
    let frameArrtribute = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)?.frame ?? CGRect.zero
```

And use convertPoint:fromView: method . to convert from its frame in collection to it's from in collection's superview

```
    let frame = collectionView.convert(frameArrtribute, to: collectionView.superView)
```