# Find out transparent area of UIBUtton

Tags: ios

I have UIImage of which half part is transparent,and i have set that image to the UIButton now.Now i want to give touch event to that UIButton.
But I want to give touch to the non-transparent are area of UIButton(image).Any body please help me.

Answer (score 1):

you do not need UIButton for this. Use simple UIImageView and add UITapGestureRecognizer to that imageView.

Then you can get the touch coordinates: 
[How do I get the coordinates for finger tapping in UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113860/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-for-finger-tapping-in-uiview)

and calculate if this coordinates is on the transparent part of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the image to a UIButton, you could create a transparent UIView and add it on top of the image where you want to respond to touches. You could then add a UITapGestureRecogniser to that view saving you mucking around with coordinates etc.

```
let tapView = UIView(frame: CGRect(0,50, 50, 25))   // change frame to suit
tapView.alpha = 0
let tapGesture = UIGestureRecogniser(target: self, action: "myAction")
tapView.addGestureRecogniser(tapGesture)
myImageView.addSubview(tapView)

// etc

func myAction(){
    // some action
}
```